# Build a docker image using python docker sdk

Tags: python, dockerfile, dockerpy

I have the following structure

```
- Dockerfile
|
_ apps
    |
    -myapi
      |
      - api-1.0.8.json
```

In the Dockerfile, I have this

```
FROM mybase

# Simply need to update config file
ARG asset_api=myapi
ARG asset_api_version=1.0.8
COPY $PWD/apps/${asset_api}/api-${asset_api_version}.json /api.json
```

This works fine when running CLI `docker build` command

Using the [docker sdk for python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html#docker.models.images.ImageCollection.build), I created my `api.py` file like this

```
client.images.build(path="./", tag = 'myimage:tag', buildargs={'asset_api': 'myapi', 'asset_api_version': '1.0.8'}, use_config_proxy=True)
```

I keep getting this error

```
docker.errors.BuildError: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder289614590/apps/myapi/api-1.0.8.json: no such file or directory
```

How do I make sure the the file is copied to the build context?

Comment: Hopefully you have figured something out by now. The problem most likely stems from the `$PWD` part in your Dockerfile. You still needing help with this?